# Login not working, error

Tags: android

I have problem in login. I will be grateful if you solve this. I cant login. I cant find out the error in this so please tell me the error if any one there

this is my login code :

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import android.app.ActionBar;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Executive_Login extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int flag = 1;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPassword;
    ExecutiveSessionManager session;


    public static final String EMAIL = "email";

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://www.topwebdevcompany.com/app/api/executive-login.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_executive__login);

        session = new ExecutiveSessionManager(getApplicationContext());


        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

/*
        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
*/
    }

    public void checkLogin(View v) {

        //if(session.getUserName(LoginActivity.this).length()==0)
        //{
        new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        //}//
        //else
        //  {
        //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        //  startActivity(i);
        //}
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Executive_Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging In..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();


            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gmail", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    flag = 0;

                    session.createUserLoginSession("Android Example",
                            name);

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dealer.class);
                    i.putExtra("email", name);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    flag = 1;
                    // username / password doesn't match&
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username/Password is incorrect",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (flag == 1)
                Toast.makeText(Executive_Login.this, "Please Enter Correct informations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

My executivesessionmanager code is:
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by hp-pc on 10/28/2016.
 */
public class ExecutiveSessionManager {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "AndroidExamplePref";
    private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public ExecutiveSessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }
    public void createUserLoginSession(String name, String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Executive_Login.class);

            // Closing all the Activities from stack
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

        //Use hashmap to store user credentials
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }
/*static  SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx)
{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}
    public static void setUserName(Context ctx,String username)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        ed.putString( PREFER_NAME ,username);
        ed.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx) {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREFER_NAME,"");
    }

    {

    }*/
    /**
     *
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){

        // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Executive_Login.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    // Check for login
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);
    }


}
and my xml file is :
```

"If any one can tell what is the error in this code because after clicking on login button i came out of the application
This is code of JSONParser of the respective file thorugh which i have done parsing....

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: show us a logcat error

Comment: Did you check logcat.Error/Message ?

Comment: Please provide the error log

Comment: show your error code

Comment: Sir it does not show any error but my app get crashed

Comment: Check your logcat. It will show you crashed logs.

Comment: otherwise debug the code and find out at which place the app get crashing then tell us

Comment: I did nt get any error log there..

Comment: Have you tried to debug this ?

Comment: yes.. but cant get any error

Comment: 11-07 16:26:48.076 11052-11052/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
11-07 16:26:48.085 12272-12272/? W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 12272

Comment: @MeghaJain Please privide code of JSONParser class.

Comment: @Deepak I have added the code of JSONParser with the question please check it out..

Comment: @MeghaJain : It will great for all if you could post logcat for same. If that is not working you may try debugging the code and getting exact point of error. Still I have posted my way of parsing. You may wish to editing it and trying your way.

Comment: @MeghaJain Can you please provide any login credentials ?

Comment: @MeghaJain I have posted solution with modifying some of your code. try that, I think it will work for you.

Comment: @DeepakSachdeva: Sir the problem is now......  int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: @MeghaJain can you post the json response here ?

Comment: JSON response??

Comment: yes, either you can provide the login credentials.

Comment: Email is meghajain308@gmail.com    pasword is 123456

Comment: @MeghaJain code is working fine. I have used your credentials and got the output:
{"message":"No product found","success":0}
int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
so valuse of success will be 0 and else block will call.

Comment: but its still crashed

Comment: @MeghaJain can you provide crash logs ?

Comment: now it show error in JSONParser

Comment: i cant post my logcat here

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way of parsing ... Publishing for both POST and GET methods.

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.kspl.kard.R;
import com.kspl.kard.constant.Constants;
import com.kspl.kard.util.SharedPrefUtil;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Created by vivek on 17/5/16.
 */
public class HttpServerConnection implements Constants{

    private StringBuilder response;
    private StringBuilder responseOutput;
    private String uri;
    private Context context;
    private String TAG = "HttpServerConnection";
    private static HttpURLConnection httpConn;

    public HttpServerConnection(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.response = new StringBuilder();
        this.responseOutput =  new StringBuilder();
    }

    public String getParsedData(String jsonData, String method_name, String server_method, String header_value)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + method_name);
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
            httpConn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            if(header_value.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Mobile-No", SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(context, "mobile_no", ""));
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-GCM-Id", SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.sp_gcm_id), "", "gcm"));
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("X-Device-Id", SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.dev_id), "", "dev_id"));
            }
            /**/
            httpConn.setRequestMethod(server_method); // This will be based on

            if (jsonData != null && jsonData.length() > 0)
            {
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(jsonData.length()));
                OutputStream os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                outputStreamWriter.write(jsonData);
                outputStreamWriter.close();
            }
            else
            {
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(2));
                OutputStream os = httpConn.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");
                outputStreamWriter.write("{}");
                outputStreamWriter.close();
            }

            int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == 200)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                if (httpConn != null) {
                    inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
                }

                String line;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            }
            else if(responseCode == 401)
            {
                response.append("{\"code\":401,\"message\":\" User session expired. Please Re-login.\",\"status\":false}");
            }
            else
            {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                if (httpConn != null)
                {
                    inputStream = httpConn.getErrorStream();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new IOException("Connection is not established.");
                }

                String line;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            }
            System.out.println("=========== MAIN SERVER RESPONSE ============== " + response.toString());
            if (httpConn != null)
                httpConn.disconnect();
        } catch (UnknownHostException one) {
            response.append("{\"code\":0,\"message\":\"No internet connection. Please try after some time.\",\"status\":false}");
            //response.append("{\"message\":" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_1) + ",\"status\":\"error\"}");
        } catch (SocketException two) {
            response.append("{\"code\":0,\"message\":\" Seems like we are not able to sync with server. Please try after some time. \",\"status\":false}");
            //response.append("{\"message\":" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_2) + ",\"status\":\"error\"}");
        } catch (Exception three) {
            response.append("{\"code\":0,\"message\":\" Server error. Please try after some time. \",\"status\":false}");
            //response.append("{\"message\":" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.server_3) + ",\"status\":\"error\"}");
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    // Get Request
    public String getParedDatGet(String complete_url, String need_header)
    {
        String get_response = null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
        url = new URL(complete_url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");


        /*connection.setRequestProperty("USER-AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("ACCEPT-LANGUAGE", "en-US,en;0.5");*/

        if(need_header.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        {
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Mobile-No", SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(context, "mobile_no", ""));
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-GCM-Id", SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.sp_gcm_id), ""));
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-Device-Id", SharedPrefUtil.getSharedPref(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.dev_id), ""));
        }

         connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        switch (responseCode)
        {
            case 200:
                final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Request URL " + url);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode);
                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Type " + "GET");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println("output===============" + br);
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();

                output.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response " + System.getProperty("line.separator") + System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString());

                get_response = responseOutput.toString();
                System.out.println("========== GET RESPONSE IS ======== " + get_response);
                break;

            case 401:
                responseOutput.append("{\"code\":401,\"message\":\" User session expired. Please Re-login.\",\"status\":false}");
                get_response = responseOutput.toString();
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            get_response = "";
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            get_response = "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            get_response = "";
        }

        return get_response;
    }

} // End of server connection class over here ...
```

Still you can modify code if required at your end. You may have to change code for the way of getting request. For Ex: Here I am putting request in form of JSON Object.

Cheers!
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen you have implement some of the code in doInBackground that should be used in onPostExecute method. I have modified some of your code. Use your login credentials. May be it works for you. Use your JSONParser class same.

```
public class Executive_Login extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int flag = 1;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputPassword;
    ExecutiveSessionManager session;
    String name;
    String password;

    public static final String EMAIL = "email";

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://www.topwebdevcompany.com/app/api/executive-login.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_executive__login);

        session = new ExecutiveSessionManager(getApplicationContext());


//        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
//        actionBar.hide();

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
               checkLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkLogin() {

        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        //if(session.getUserName(LoginActivity.this).length()==0)
        //{
        new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        //}//
        //else
        //  {
        //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        //  startActivity(i);
        //}
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     */
    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        JSONObject json;
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Executive_Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging In..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gmail", "abc@gmail.com"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "abc"));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());



            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    flag = 0;

                    session.createUserLoginSession("Android Example",
                            name);

//                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dealer.class);
//                    i.putExtra("email", name);
//                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//
//                    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
//                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    flag = 1;
                    // username / password doesn't match&
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username/Password is incorrect",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if (flag == 1)
                Toast.makeText(Executive_Login.this, "Please Enter Correct informations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}



/**
 * Created by hp-pc on 10/28/2016.
 */
 class ExecutiveSessionManager {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "AndroidExamplePref";
    private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    public ExecutiveSessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }
    public void createUserLoginSession(String name, String email){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, name);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Executive_Login.class);

            // Closing all the Activities from stack
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

        //Use hashmap to store user credentials
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // user name
        user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }
/*static  SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx)
{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
}
    public static void setUserName(Context ctx,String username)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        ed.putString( PREFER_NAME ,username);
        ed.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx) {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREFER_NAME,"");
    }

    {

    }*/
    /**
     *
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){

        // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Executive_Login.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    // Check for login
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);
    }
}
```